# How to avoid very long if` statement during form processing?

Tags: php, forms

On each example of form processing I found this scenario:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {...
```

... and than - so many lines (sometimes about 250) which belongs to the above `if`.
Very unsuitable to track.

Is there a way like this:
`if(empty($_POST)) {`show show some message or echo... anything`}`, and then - stop the code
So all next lines will be `outside of very long if` and they'll still execute only if that `if` is satisfied.

I tried something, but the members of `$_POST` (username, pass...) in this case are not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function that will execute the code necessary and pass the $_POST variable as an argument. In that way the required variables (e.g. username, password) are now available in the function

```
function executePost($post) {
   // execute code here with $post variables
   $username = $post['username'];
   $password = $post['password'];
}
```

You call the function after you checked the post

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    executePost($_POST);
} else {
   echo 'Post was empty';
}
```

Comment: @Alegro You should probably start by reading this: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Answer (score 2):

When you are inside a function you can use `return` inside the `if(empty($_POST)) {...}`. Otherwise you can use `die(message)` or `exit()` to stop the whole script execution.

Comment: Thanks, it that case how to handle `username, pass...`, because they are unavailable outside of `$_POST`

Comment: what do you mean by outside of $_POST ? you can use them easily as you want

Comment: @Alegro There's no such thing as "outside of `$_POST`". `$_POST` is a superglobal, which means it's available anywhere in your script without having to specifically pass it around or mark it global. The only way it goes away is if you call `unset($_POST)` to destroy it.

Comment: @AgentConundrum, thanks a lot. For some reason my `$_POST` is not `available anywhere`. I didn't `unset` it, tried with `session_start`... but, I will check. Thanks, anyway.